# Dual Graphics Cards

Tags: windows, sli

I just recently built myself a new windows box, and I still have a lot of my old components. In my new box I am running an SLI capable mobo with a geForce GTX 295, and from my old box I have a geForce 9600 GT OC. Is it possible to put both cards in my new box and have the lower card dedicated to a TV out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, but expect problems since you don't have two *SAME* graphic cards.  I tried for example same NVidia family of cards, but different models - one was plan other GT, and it worked, but I experienced some flickering while starting some applications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work without problems. You should see both devices in the hardware management and if you configure the monitors correctly, it should work as I understand you want it.